# Complex numbers involving triangle ABC.

Tags: complex-numbers

Please help me solve this problem, I've tried sketching a triangle on axes of Real against Imaginary number. But don't know how to proceed. Should I treat $v$ and $u$ as vectors? Should I apply $AB= v - u$? 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline, but you will need to do the calculations yourself.

1. Indeed, you need to get $AB$ first as $u-v$
2. What's the slope of the line? Say $m$
3. The slope of BC is $-1/m$
4. Write the equation of a line going through $B$, with a slope $-1/m$
5. Choose a point $C$ on this line. Write the distance to $B$, $|C-B|$.
6. This last one is twice $|u-v|$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sum, subtraction and modulus you can treat the complex numbers as vectors.
by $AB$ I suppose it is intended the length of the segment, thus $|u-v|$.